# postgresql error while trying to modulu Pi

Tags: postgresql

I want to something like:

```
select tan(angle) % (2*Pi())
```

Hence I get the folowing error: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric % double precision` any suggestions?

Comment: Modulo (remainder) operator have sense on the integer arguments. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator in postgres takes *NUMERIC* as arguments. Thus, you have to cast the operands:

```
SELECT TAN(angle)::NUMERIC % (2 * PI())::NUMERIC;
```